# Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /var/git/.ssh/authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, authentication, sshd, home, key-authentication

**EDIT**

> The issue as exposed here is
>   solved (about files modes of the `.ssh` folder.
>
> But an other issue persists so I create a new question : > [Unable to login with SSH-RSA key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205842/unable-to-login-with-ssh-rsa-key)

I can no longer connect with ssh-rsa key for a specific user, but it still work for other users.

The `git` user defined as follow :

```
# cat /etc/passwd | grep git
git:x:1002:1002:,,,:/var/git:/bin/bash
```

So you noticed that this is the git user thus its home is `/var/git`, it's not in `/home`.

Now, ssh always prompt me for password :

```
$ ssh git@srv
git@srv's password:
```

I checked logs :

```
# tail -n 1 /var/log/auth.log
[...] Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /var/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

So `authorized_keys` as some ownership or modes missconfiguration. 
I don't understand because here is the conf for this file :

```
# ls -l /var/git/.ssh/ | grep auth
-rw-rw-r-- 1 git git 394 mai   22 17:39 authorized_keys
```

And here is (in case...) the parent `.ssh` dir:

```
# ls -al /var/git/ | grep ssh
drwxrwxr-x  2 git  git  4096 mai   22 17:39 .ssh
```

And the `$HOME` directory :

```
# ls -l /var/ | grep git
drwxr-xr-x  7 git  git    4096 mai   27 10:49 git
```

So owners are always `git`, like owner groups. And files are readable so where could be the trick ?

Comment: Does the `.ssh` directory actually *require* group-write access and on all of its files as well?

Comment: @Nasha the exact oppposite - permissions here are too lax - as answered below by Otheus and damienfrancois.

Comment: Well, I meant «*as per your setup, can you consider restricting rights on the .ssh folder without impeding your installation?*» BTW every file (with the exception of public keys) in the `.ssh` directory *must* (at least *should*) be read/write-able by the owner only, no access to group/others.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem is the fact that file and directory permissions do not meet the requirements of `StrictModes`, which in OpenSSH is `yes` by default and should not be changed. Try setting the permissions of `authorized_keys` to `0600` and the `.ssh` directory to `0700`.

```
# chmod 0700 .../.ssh/
# chmod 0600 .../.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Note that the `...` will differ based on installation (e.g., in this question it is `/var/git/` but for users it will be `/home/username/`.

Comment: Nope that's not it. authorized_keys and .ssh may be world-readable and ssh will work.

Comment: only if owned by root

Comment: It applies to any user. At least in v 5.3p1

Comment: I trust you ; though the manpage on my systems says, about `authorized_keys`:  "This file is not highly
             sensitive, but the recommended permissions are read/write for the user, and not accessible by others."

Comment: You were right. I no longer get this error now. I applyed `600` on both `authorized_keys` file and `.ssh` folder (required after getting a new error message in logs, about `.ssh` folder). But surprisingly, ssh ask me again for password, with no any error in `/var/log/auth.log`. Any idea? Do you think I have to restart sshd ?

Comment: Connect with `ssh -vv`. That _might_ provide you a hint why the public/private key authentication is failing.

Comment: Something useful is to start `sshd` in debug mode on the target machine with (from my memory so maybe not 100% accurate) `/usr/sbin/sshd -d -e -p 1234 ` so you have a sshd server  listening on port 1234 with all info spit out in the console.

Comment: (^-- and connect to port 1234 with the client via `ssh -p 1234`)

Comment: I also had to give `600` permissions to the root's home dir.

Comment: I had to give the user's home dir 755 permissions, then it worked - seems that it's very fussy about privileges (understandably so)

Comment: This didn't work for me at all. I only got mine to work after very carefully copying the permissions from a separate working machine. For me, these were: `chmod 755 $HOME`, `chmod 775 $HOME/.ssh`, `chmod 664 $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`. I'm on Ubuntu Server 20.04.

Comment: This fixes everything in one go: `chmod go-w ~/;chmod 700 ~/.ssh;chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Answer (score 6):

For reasons of paranoia, the `.ssh` directory and `authorized_keys` must not be group-writable. I guess the thinking is, the user must be the only one with explicit control over his/her authorization. I believe a work-around for this lies with ACL. The other work around is `StrictModes=no` setting in sshd's configuration file. But it would be too dangerous to do that for the sake of one user.

P.S. your `ls -l /var | grep git` is more concisely done as `ls -ld /var/git`

Comment: I can change out your entire .ssh directory with mine if group writable would be allowed on HOME, or .ssh. That is not paranoia but a considerable risk.

Comment: Anytime permissions for a user's home dir are set to group-writable, it's a considerable risk. But there are times when we know exactly what we're doing. It pisses me off the SSH team seems to assume the user doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

The `$HOME/.ssh` directory mode *must* be 700 and `authorized_keys` *should* be readable by the owner only, i.e. mode 600:

```
chmod u=rwx,g=,o= /var/git/.ssh
chmod u=rw,g=,o= /var/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

As to the private key, it *must* be read-write-able by the owner only:

```
chmod u=rw,g=,o= /var/git/.ssh/id_?sa
```

Comment: What version are you running, Nasha? Have you actually tested this? That is, have you tested that og must not be read-execute?

Comment: I'm using *ssh-server-6.2p2* on Mint. Works the same on Gentoo. I've been using this setup for quite some time without a problem. My SSH server runs as root BTW.

Comment: @Otheus me --> /facepalm/ :-D Sometimes you can't spot the wrong bit looking too closely at it...

Comment: Actually 700 and 600 are safest way to do.  However 660 might work: if the user's group has no other users in it!  I learnt it the hard way, the working login was denied after I added another user to the group, lol.

Comment: @lol I also saw _exactly_ this and it got me puzzled... I added a new user to the user's group, and suddenly `authorized_keys`-based authentication stopped working. If someone could locate information about this behaviour in the documentation, it would be great.