# chmod doesn't help for "Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes"

Tags: ssh, sshd

Foreword: I believe I did my homework. **I tried checking the ownership/modes of the relevant files**, but I'm still getting the error.

I'm trying to start an SFTP server on GNU/Linux. I made a new user called `sftp_server`, created `/home/sftp_server/.ssh`, and filled `/home/sftp_server/.ssh/sshd_config` with:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /home/sftp_server/.ssh/authorized_keys
HostKey /home/sftp_server/.ssh/server_key
Subsystem       sftp internal-sftp

PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

Port 2222
AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
ListenAddress ::
```

Then I added the client's public key to `/home/sftp_server/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

I ran server as `sftp_server`:

```
sftp_server@system ~> /usr/bin/sshd -f /home/sftp_server/.ssh/sshd_config -D -d
```

and it launches successfully with

```
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_8.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020
…
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
```

But my attempt to connect to this server from the client with

```bsh
user@DESKTOP:~$ sftp -P 2222 192.168.0.102
```

fails (on the server side) with:

```
…
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /home/sftp_server/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: restore_uid: (unprivileged)
Failed publickey for user from 192.168.0.103 port 64450 ssh2: ED25519 SHA256:...
Connection closed by authenticating user user 192.168.0.103 port 64450 [preauth]
…
```

**UPDATE**: Logging in as `sftp_server` doesn't help either.

```
user@DESKTOP:~$ sftp -P 2222 sftp_server@192.168.0.102
```

fails on the server side with the same error message.

This is a server-side message, so I'm assuming the server is failing to access the `authorized_keys` file properly.

The existing questions

- [Why am I still getting a password prompt with ssh with public key authentication?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36540/104028)
- [Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /var/git/.ssh/authorized_keys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205830/104028)

both advises that I should set ownership/modes properly, like:

```bsh
$ sudo chmod 0700 /home/sftp_server/.ssh
$ sudo chmod 0600 /home/sftp_server/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

But I've already applied these.

```bsh
[root@system user]# ls -al /home
…
drwxr-xr-x   7 sftp_server root        4096 Mar 24 15:07 sftp_server
…

[root@system user]# ls -al /home/sftp_server
drwxr-xr-x 7 sftp_server root       4096 Mar 24 15:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root        root       4096 Nov 17  2018 ..
…
drwx------ 2 sftp_server sftp_users 4096 Mar 24 14:53 .ssh
…

[root@system user]# ls -al /home/sftp_server/.ssh
…
drwx------ 2 sftp_server sftp_users 4096 Mar 24 14:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 sftp_server root       4096 Mar 24 15:07 ..
-rw------- 1 sftp_server sftp_users  162 Mar 24 14:15 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 sftp_server sftp_users  410 Mar 24 14:53 sshd_config
…
```

I'm thinking that

- `drwxr-xr-x` (755) for `/home/sftp_server`
- `drwx------` (700) for `/home/sftp_server/.ssh`
- `-rw-------` (600) for `/home/sftp_server/.ssh/authorized_keys`

are the correct modes, and they all correctly have `sftp_server` set as the file owner.

This leaves me puzzled and frustrated for the `bad ownership or modes for file` error message.

I'd appreciate any help or hint. Thanks!

Comment: But you login as *user* thus shouldn't *user* be owner of `authorized_keys`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I clarified the question. Logging in as `sftp_server` results in the same error.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak Could you elaborate? What directory does `..` refer to? At least in my `ls` snippet, all `..` directories already have the `drwxr-xr-x` modes, I think?

Comment: It refers to _(going to) upper directory_ as for my understanding or the upper directory itsself, have never fiddled with this specifically. = The group should not be root I assume.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak I know what `..` means, I asked what directory you referred to. What file/directory do you suggest to change? `/home` or `/home/sftp_server` or `/home/sftp_server/.ssh`? Which property of that file/directory? By the way, I tried changing the group of `/home/sftp_server` but it had no effect. I also doubt it's the group, because the error says "bad ownership or modes."

Comment: `ls -l /home/sftp_server/.ssh/server_key` ?

Comment: You are not showing all output, as @ilkkachu wrote, where is `server_key`? Anyway, the setup you want works fine, I just tested it. BTW, `debug1: restore_uid: (unprivileged)` shows you are running this SSH daemon as ordinary user - `sftp_server`. What distro do you use?

Comment: I know it doesn't complain about `server_key`. But AFAIK, it should test that one too, so it occurred to me you might want to check that too.

Comment: Sorry but as you are confused what info you give us, then I bet it is some PEBKAC issue, see it works https://gist.github.com/jirib/e0ec851d47813bb091b754d71e83e786 If you are desperate set *StrictMode* to false (`man sshd_config`).

Comment: Can you add `ls -ld / /home` to your question, please (permissions for `/` and `/home` themselves). I suspect it may be a permissions/ownership issue up the chain of directories from `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: I tried to dig at the code to see what it does, but as far as I can see, it a) only checks for write permissions, read access should be ok, b) problems with directories should get a different error message: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_8_4/misc.c (Debian has a patch to allow group-writable files if the group is one where the user is the sole member; this is to support per-user groups and a `002` umask.) Based on the code, the settings here look ok to me...

Answer (score -1):

Your sftp command is wrong. It should be like this:

`sftp -P 2222 sftp_server@192.168.0.102`

With your current command, you are logging in to the server with user `user`, which doesn't exist on server side.

Comment: That's not the problem. As the error message says, the server thinks the file `/home/sftp_server/.ssh/authorized_keys` is (somehow) wrong. I edited the question to clarify that adding `sftp_server@` on the client side doesn't help.